# Existing "God" won't load and monitor correctly

Tags: ruby, god

Very simple question. Is this by design, or a bug?.

First, I have a very simple ruby script that waits 5 seconds, then throws an Exception.

```
#t.rb#
sleep 5
raise 'ex'
```

And a god config file of

```
 #numanagedev.conf#
 God.watch do |w|
    w.name = "Numanage"
         w.start = "ruby t.rb"#"/Users/jonathan/.rvm/bin/god_puma -p 3000"
         w.keepalive
         w.dir ="/Users/jonathan/projects/numanage"
 end
```

when I run `god -c numanagedev.conf`, and watch the logs and it works perfectly.

```
 jonathan@Jonathans-MacBook-Pro-2 ~> god log Numanage
 Please wait...
 I [2017-05-08 18:10:09]  INFO: Numanage [trigger] process 6563 exited (ProcessExits)
 I [2017-05-08 18:10:09]  INFO: Numanage move 'up' to 'start'
 I [2017-05-08 18:10:09]  INFO: Numanage deregistered 'proc_exit' event for pid 6563
 I [2017-05-08 18:10:09]  INFO: Numanage start: ruby t.rb
 I [2017-05-08 18:10:09]  INFO: Numanage moved 'up' to 'start'
 I [2017-05-08 18:10:09]  INFO: Numanage [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
 I [2017-05-08 18:10:09]  INFO: Numanage move 'start' to 'up'
 I [2017-05-08 18:10:09]  INFO: Numanage registered 'proc_exit' event for pid 6573
 I [2017-05-08 18:10:09]  INFO: Numanage moved 'start' to 'up'
```

But when I start a `god` process, and then load it `god load numanagedev.conf`, nothing shows up in the logs. It should be stopping and starting again. But `god status` says its running